# Programmatic import in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a directory `foo` that contains some `.py` files.

Each of these python files has a class `Bar` defined.

Say there were three `.py` files called  `baz.py`, `qux.py` and `quux.py` - then to get the bar classes I could write:

```
import foo.baz
import foo.qux
import foo.quux

bars = [
    foo.baz.Bar,
    foo.qux.Bar,
    foo.quux.Bar,
]
```

However, rather than list out all the imports like this and all the `Bar` names, I want to populate `bars` programmatically.

That is, I want to write some code to populate `bars` that doesn't change as `.py` files are added or removed from the `foo` directory.

One way to do this might be to use `Path('foo').iterdir()` to list the `.py` files, but then how do I do a programmatic `import` of a string and name its `Bar` class?

Or is there some totally different approach to achieve this?

```
bars = []
for py_file in the directory foo:
   import foo.py_file  ???
   bars.append(foo.py_file.Bar)  ???
```

Comment: Take a look at the built-in package [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using [`glob`](https://docs.python.orgto/3.8/library/glob.html) module to match the pathnames of the modules we would like to import and [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)'s [`SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader) to import.

```
from glob import glob
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

modules = glob('foo/*.py')

bars = list(map(lambda pathname: SourceFileLoader(".", pathname).load_module().Bar, modules))
```

Comment: I don't understand what `SourceFileLoader(".", ...)` does.  What does it mean to pass `"."` as the `fullname` parameter to `SourceFileLoader` ?  Will any import statements contained in the loaded files continue to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib` to import the modules dynamically. But you need to find them first. If you include `foo.__init__.py` in the source, then then `foo.__file__` will be that name. You can use that as the base of your glob, but you need to make sure you don't try to import `__init__.py` itself. This technique is nice because you don't have to worry about another bit of source importing the same module name but getting a different module in memory.

```
from pathlib import Path
import importlib
import foo

def no_magic(paths):
    for path in paths:
        if not path.name.startswith("_"):
            yield path

bars = []
for py in no_magic(Path(foo.__file__).resolve().parent.glob("*.py")):
    mod = importlib.import_module(f"foo.{py.stem}", foo)
    bars.append(mod.Bar)

print(bars)
```